# AngularJS: HTML select to use values from map with ascending order on key

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have map(Bidirectional) of States. Which composed of stateName and stateCode.
It is populated by following HTML code but cannot filter by stateCode or stateName in ascending order.

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
              <select ng-model="location.stateCode"  ng-change="loadDistricts();" ng-options="stateName for (stateCode, stateName) in stateOptions | orderBy:'stateCode'" class="form-control" id="state"></select>
</div>

//Json Object
    stateOptions = {'MH':'Maharashtra','GJ':'Gujarat','MP':'Madhya Pradesh'};
```

Comment: If the key is `stateCode` you should have `for (stateCode, stateName)` instead of `for (stateName, stateCode)`

Comment: @Michael - Thanks for comment, i also tried by doing it. In both way it does not populate by ascending order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You inverted `stateCode` and `stateName`:

```
ng-options="stateName for (stateCode, stateName) in stateOptions"
```

Also, as `stateOptions` is an object, the keys will *probably* be inserted alphabetically, depending on the js virtual machine. The `orderBy` filter is here pointless, because (from [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy)):

> Orders a specified array by the expression predicate. It is ordered alphabetically for strings and numerically for numbers

See **[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwqg4gyf/3/)**

---

**Edit:** If you want to surely control the order, rework your structure as an array:

```
$scope.stateOptions = [{
    stateCode: 'MH',
    stateName:'Maharashtra'
},{
    stateCode: 'GJ',
    stateName:'Gujarat'
},{
    stateCode: 'MP',
    stateName:'Madhya Pradesh'
}];

ng-options="state.stateName for state in stateOptions | orderBy: 'stateCode'"
```

See **[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hwqg4gyf/4/)**

Comment: Hello @Michael - I edited the question, it does not work in either way.

Comment: Hello @Michael- Thank you, but still it is not sorted. What will be option for that, or can i sort it using js and then render it.

Comment: You will have to pass an array to `ng-options`. See edit in answer

Comment: Yes ! This will definitely solve the problem. Thanks you so much.

Comment: Glad we *sorted* this out:)

Answer (score 0):

Another way

```
    <select ng-model="location.stateCode" ng-change="loadDistricts();" 

     ng-options="stateName for (stateCode, stateName) in stateOptions | orderBy:'toString()' | filter:stateCode" 

     class="form-control" id="state">
```

Comment: Hello @Aditya- Thank you for posting answer. But there is a problem by using it, it gives error- Filter:notarray.

Answer (score 0):

This will be also good option if we do not want to re-structure our object.
Fist sort our map object based on keys then pass it to ng-options.

```
$scope.stateOptions = sortObject($scope.stateOptions);

function sortObject(obj) {
            return Object.keys(obj).sort().reduce(function (result, key) {
            result[key] = obj[key];
            return result;
        }, {});}
```